# Keep round rectangle's radius when scaling

Tags: flash, scaling

I want to scale my round rectangle and keep it's radius from been changed. How can I do that?

I am exporting SWF to flex and drawing it there. I do not want to scale it at run time, I just need few sets of scales.

Comment: Is that a library asset or do you draw the rectangle in ActionScript? Are you scaling with the mouse in your IDE or in code?

Comment: @weltraumpirat tnx, question been updated, please review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [scale9Grid](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scale9Grid) property of your display object ('`dob`'). Try something like this:

```
dob.scale9Grid = new Rectangle( cornerRadius, cornerRadius, dob.width - 2*cornerRadius, dob.height- 2*cornerRadius ) ;
```